# How does this garden solar light work?

Tags: solar-cell, pnp

[image: Solar Garden Light]

I do not understand how this circuit powers on the load (the LED light).

When the solar panel is inactive, i.e. it is dark, there will be a small current from emitter to base, and that will allow the larger current from battery to flow through the load, turning the LED on.

I do not understand how the small current from emitter to base makes it back to the negative terminal of the battery, how is it getting to ground?

Comment: rosewater - To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the PDF / video / webpage name and its link, for the source of that copied image. (And please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too). TY

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I do not understand how the small current from emitter to base makes it back to the negative terminal of the battery, how is it getting to ground?

Individual [PV cell](https://g2voptics.com/photovoltaics-solar-cells/theory-of-solar-cells) is like a diode
[image]

so it can conduct current in the reversed (I mean forward bias) if you supply higher voltage to its positive terminal. In your circuit, since the battery has higher potential than the solar panel in the dark, the current will conduct through the emitter-base of the PNP and through the PV cells and finally reaching the negative terminal of the battery.

[image]

An interesting phenomenon if you conduct current into the PV cells is that it will emit photons just like ordinary LEDs, but the wavelengths will be in the non-visible IR region. This is one of the methods to evaluate/analyze solar panels to see if they are good or bad.

It is a terrible idea to conduct **large** current into the PV cells, so most commercial photovoltaic arrays have blocking diode connected in series to prevent that from happening. This means it will not work if you used them in your circuit.

Comment: The PV cell is not only "like a diode", it is a full-featured diode with its own pn transition and different resistance in forward and reverse direction. On the other hand, I wonder how it opens in forward direction at voltages this low (e.g. 0.3V per cell)

Comment: Thank you explaining like that with the clear drawing

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how forcing current through a solar cell makes it act like an LED, emitting infrared, and indicating if it is good or not.

Answer (score 9):

Some circuits should be redrawn to de-clutter: -

[image]

> *How does this garden solar light work?*

- When the solar panel illuminates and produces up to 4.5 volts, the 1N914 is in the charge path to the battery and reduces the battery voltage to no more than 3.8 volts
- In fact the battery will limit this to around 3 volts so, in fact the solar cell probably never generates more than 3.7 volts in full brightness
- The PNP transistor's base-emitter region is reverse biased and the yellow LED is not illuminated
- At night, the solar panel voltage is minimal and this activates the PNP transistor and current flows in the LED. In effect the circuit becomes: -

[image]

Comment: I almost want to offer a bounty just for redrawing the circuit!

Answer (score 4):

The solar cells, along with charging the battery, are connected to the base of the transistor through the resistor. The transistor is a PNP so it is on when the base is 0.7 V below the emitter voltage.

When the solar panels are dark they will have very little voltage so the base will be pulled down towards 0 V, the collector is at the battery voltage so the transistor turns on.

When there is light on the solar cell it will have a higher voltage than the battery, the base will then be pulled higher than the collector and the transistor will turn off.