# How to bright up LED when it's dark without wasting battery energy?

Tags: led, light, phototransistor, photoresistor

I am trying to design night light LED that brights up when it's dark. I know a solution using transistor that "drains" current so LED has not enough to light up.

[image]

A current flow through transistor during day to "block" led. I can't get out of my head that waste of energy if the source is a small battery or super-capacitor.

---

I wonder if there is a solution to make night light without unnecessary current drain. It would be disappointing if that needs complex stuff like IC, op-amp or comparator ...

**Is there a nice circuit using basic components that does not waste energy?**

*Correct me if you see anything wrong, I am new to electronics.*

Thank you.

Comment: [Try this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699952/how-does-this-garden-solar-light-work/699962#699962)

Comment: LDRs always let *more* current through when it is light, so I can't imagine how you could reverse that. There might be a solution that uses a photodiode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. That circuit does waste energy. The reason is you want your light sensor (CdS resistor?) to shunt current to your amplifying element (the transistor) NOT the load (the LED) as in your case. The idea is that the transistor amplifies the uA's of current as opposed to burning mA's of current - a savings of 1000x worth of battery juice! Try the following to get you going:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8SIfL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 can be whatever single NPN transistor that you are already using, however, the Darlington should give you better performance due to high gain (less current needed, sharper transition). You might need lower value resistors in the single NPN case. Also, if the LED still stays "on" even dimly in bright conditions, and you don't like that, put a highish value resistor across the base and emitter of the transistor to control the gain and "force" the LED off in bright conditions.

Comment: Thank you! In simulation it seems working. There is also garden light solution by Andy I will look at that. This might work, I am again a little bit smarter now.

Just wonder, what if I make tripled NPN transistor to amplify even more and save more energy? Will it work in reality?

Comment: Slow down. You're not ready for a Darlington Triple. You will have to start considering real life issues when you start cascading multiple transistors like that - in theory, the gain will go up and you can use higher value resistors for less current consumption, however, now the gate is going to be ultra sensitive to noise. You also get more leakage current which gets amplified by the next stage. Both of these issues can be mitigated with a resistor across the BE junction, but now you are undermining exactly what your are trying to achieve - you are at diminishing returns at 2 MAYBE 3 Q's

Comment: BTW, Andy's circuit is great too. I didn't know a solar panel was available in the design - that could double as light sensor and not just a charging element.

Comment: Darlington BJT pairs need more V(be) to turn on due to the chained BJTs. A triple Darlington will only make this worse as you then need 3 times the original base-emitter voltage to turn it on, which can be difficult in low-voltage situations(i.e. a battery).